# Isotope Filter mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools, jquery-isotope

I am trying to make isotope works with filter the same elements but by two ways, one is filter by links and the other filter by buttons like a carrusel. The links will filter the subgrups, I have 4 groups plus the all elements, and when I click each one just want to show the first two elements of the group and by the left right arrow buttons the next and before elements. I made the group filter works but the carrusell I dont know why I cant...Thanks if anyone can help me with an example.

```
            var related = $(this.options.itemsBlock);                  

            if (related) {
                var isoFilter = new Isotope(related, {
                    itemSelector: '.item',
                    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
                    sortAscending: {
                        name: true,
                        datesusc: false
                    }
                });

                if (isoFilter) {

                    var buttons = $$('#filters a');

                    buttons.addEvent('click', function (e) {
                        e = new Event(e);
                        e.stop();

                        var dataFilter = this.get('data-filter');

                        isoFilter.arrange({
                            filter: dataFilter
                        });
                    });

                    var selectors = $$(this.options.selectorButtons);

                    if (selectors) {
                        selectors.removeEvents('click');
                        selectors.addEvent('click', function (e) {
                            e = new Event(e);
                            e.stop();

                            var dataFilter1 = '.g1-item-1'; // Just an example of the next two element from the first group
                            isoFilter.arrange({ filter: dataFilter1 });
                        });
                    }
                }
```

Comment: no idea what your problem actually is. you don't specify versions (this looks like ancient mootools 1.11 code with `new Event(e)`), no link to this isotop you speak of, no description of the problem, no example (use jsfiddle or similar). you are unlikely to get any help